# In a Jupyter notebook, how can I colour a displayed dataframe by dataframe object?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Hard to phrase, here's what I mean:

The problem:

I have a number of dataframes on which to get up to speed. I am therefore staring at a wall of tables in Jupyter. Assuming (weakly) that I use `display()` to render these, is there a way to colour them so that if I add new columns to one, or change it in some other way, it will retain the same colour / style when displayed, but another dataframe can have a (perhaps) different colour assigned to it?

The intention is that the visual cue will make it easier for me to quickly distinguish the tables. Here are some pseudo-examples:

```py
display(df1_in_red) # red
df1_in_red.giraffe = 'yellow'
display(df1_in_red) # still red

display(df2_in_blue) # blue
display(df2_in_blue.copy()) # green
...
```

The solution should be as flexible as possible and tie back to the dataframe's corresponding python `object`. Bells & Whistles: Auto-increment colour, merges merge colours....

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Did you read the pandas Styler docs? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Styler-Object-and-HTML